# Put an image in a texture in Android

Tags: android, image, loading, textures

I don't have any problem managing textures. But I didn't work that much with loading textures from images. All I know is that the texture needs to be of size 2^i by 2^i.

But what's the best technique to load any images into a texture. If the images is not a square, I can fit it in the square and add two black parts to fill what is missing. But I'm not sure how to do the stretching.

So, if I have an image of let say 800x600 and I want to put it in a 512x512 square, what's the best trick to copy the pixels into texture ? Or, specially on Android, is there some functions that exists that would do that for me ? In short, it's like I want to resize the 800x600 image to be 512x384 and put it in the texture. But I want to preserve as much information as I can.

Comment: Note you can post an [answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) to your own question and even accept it after a few days. Answers shouldn't be edited into the question, as that doesn't fit SO's Q&A format. [Code samples](http://sscce.org/), both in the [question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and answer will help others who have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

The OP Answered his own question with:

> SOLVED: a friend showed me some references that covers what I want.
>
> To resize, you can do it with the Bitmap class of Android. You can specify a Matrix, just like the one used for OpenGL to resize the Bitmap. From that point, I expect the pixels to be well preserved and will be able to put them in the texture.

If they come back and put the answer here themselves and accept it then I will delete this answer.